# Page showing all badge progress

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-progress

I like to have a look to [Unearned Badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=unearned). Sometimes, I focus myself on a badge I want to earn. On my user profile, there is the possibility to see the badge progress when choosing a badge to track.

I think it would be very interesting and addictive for people who like to earn badge to get a **page listing progress for all badges**, as a sum up. It will help us to focus on some badges.

What do you think of the idea ? Do you think it is a good idea ?

Comment: There's an app for that! Take a look at the [StinkingBadges](http://stackapps.com/questions/2982/stinkingbadges-track-your-progress-towards-long-term-badges) Stack App.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's interesting but I was thinking of an app with more/all the badges. This app is for high level badges for whom I am far away

Comment: You should be able to see all (trackable) badges on your profile. If you click the gear to select which badge to track, every badge that you haven't earned and isn't too expensive to track is listed. Does this not fit what you're looking for? You can even search the list, filter it by badge level, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but I know that. What I would like is to get a new page with all (not only trackable) badges. For example, following badges may have progress status but are not trackable : Favorite Question, Nice answer, Pundit, etc..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges has all of the badges, and a checkmark next to the ones which you've earned. It doesn't show progress, but you seem to be asking for badges which "may have progress status but are not trackable", which is somewhat contradictory.

Comment: Those badges don't have a progress status for various reasons, according to the team themselves, which is why they're not in the tracker. There are meta questions about it, either here or MSE, from when the tracker first rolled out.