# Why not show the "Next badge" progress on the badge page?

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-progress

When I go to my user page I can see my progress on my "Next badge". If Stack Overflow has the ability to show me that, why not show it on the specific badge pages, so I can see my progress toward any badge (not just the "next" one)?

It seems to me that if you consider the two facts:

- How much progress have I made towards a badge?
- What random people that I don't know have gotten this badge?

The former is far more relevant/useful.

Comment: [Related feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334434/page-showing-all-badge-progress)

Comment: Note that you can see the progress towards all badges at once in the dialog that allows you to choose which badge to track next.

Comment: To be clear, you're talking about putting progress on a page like [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question), which describes the badge in detail and shows which users have already earned it?

Comment: If you click "Choose which badge to track", then you see your progress towards all progressable badges. Not just the "next" one.